# spring-boot-security saml2 with loadbalancer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-saml2

my saml sso is working fine on test server, but the production server is in reality 2 servers and a load balancer.
I am using spring boot 3.1.4 and the only documentation I can find online refers to old stuff and mentions using a special loadbalancer context.

I am not sure how to overcome the issue in sb3. First, the spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.sp.acs.location - do I have to use the specific one for each of the two servers or not? Etering the load balancer address there at least did not work. Can anybody tell me how to go on with this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work seemlessly after the idp corrected their setting. So no changes needed, thats so great :).